# Unable to load website on url it open when I enter **www.domain.com/controller**

Tags: codeigniter

I have developed the application in CodeIgnitor **CI**. Website id  running properly on local machine.
my htaccess code is below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ROOT DIRECTORY NAME/

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my directory structure is

```
|application
|css
|js
|htaccess
|index
```

I have given the controller name in route.php for default_controller

Please let me know were I am wrong?

Comment: It is hard to know where you made mistake.Unless we know what is your CI-3 version?what is controller name, controller function and route.php

Comment: What is the error message? Is there system directory appearing?

Comment: I think your application directory is incomplete; alongside the `application` directory you should have a `system` directory containing the CodeIgniter core.

Comment: @Nishant Nair Have you configured your index.php to be removed? If not then you need to use `www.domain.com/index.php/controller` in every where.

Comment: How it is possible when system folder is missing as he says **Website id running properly on local machine**

Comment: I had given the controller name in upper case so the route file was unable to find the default controller

Answer (score 0):

> Oppz, In your file folder structurer you **forget to upload** `system` folder. It will solved all your issues.

and in `config/config.php` (Change this)

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In `.htaccess`(out side the application folder) replace this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```